# Elastic Search merge query

Tags: database, elasticsearch, querying

I'm totally new to Elastic Search querying and need help.

I have an index of products with 4 fields, let's say `diameter`, `brand`, `price`, `month`.

I need to get all the products with `diameter = 13` merged with all the products with `brand = brandino` (without duplicates) merged with all the products with `price` range of `100 to 1000`. And filter out products with `month != 10` condition.

How is my query should look like in this case?

Comment: Can you post the query that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Simple query used for 1 field searching, like:

```
"query": {
    "match": {
        "brand": "brandino"
    }
}
```

In your case, you need a query with searching multiple field, so; you should use [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-bool-query.html), like:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "match" :{
                    "diameter": 13
                }
            },
            {
                "match" :{
                    "brand": "brandino"
                }
            },
            {
                "range" :{
                    "price": {
                        "gte": 100,
                        "lte": 1000
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Read more about:

1. [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-match-query.html) query.
2. [range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-range-query.html) query.

Besides, you should take care of `text` fields like: `brand` that might be mapped as [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/keyword.html), which means that you need to write query like:

```
"brand.keyword": "brandino"
```